# How to handle goroutine execution timeout?

Tags: go

If task() keeps blocking in this code, what should I do? I have tried many methods, but none have been effective, all of which may cause memory leakage. How should I modify this code?
This is just a simulation of an extreme situation, where it is possible to encounter goroutine executing tasks that will continue to block and not release. I don't have a good idea how to handle it.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Task func(ctx context.Context)

type MultiWork struct {
    Works chan Task
    Limit chan struct{}
    Wg    sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewMultiWork(workers int) *MultiWork {
    nm := &MultiWork{
        Works: make(chan Task),
        Limit: make(chan struct{}, workers),
    }

    go func() {
        for task := range nm.Works {
            nm.Limit <- struct{}{}

            nm.Wg.Add(1)
            go func(task Task) {

                ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*2)
                defer cancel()

                task(ctx)

                <-nm.Limit
            }(task)

        }
    }()

    return nm
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    nm := NewMultiWork(10)

    task := func(ctx context.Context) {
        defer nm.Wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3600)
        fmt.Println("task finished ", rand.Intn(1000))
    }

    for range [100]struct{}{} {
        nm.Works <- task
    }

    nm.Wg.Wait()
    close(nm.Works)

    i := 25
    for i > 0 {
        fmt.Println("gn = ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        i--
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }

}
```

Actually, I just want to know how to release goroutine when its execution times out, and are there any other good methods?As task() in this code blocks for 500s, is using context to make it exit ineffective?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a switch. You can't have a `time.Sleep()`, though. You instead need to use a timer.

```
defer nm.Wg.Done()
switch {
case <-time.After(time.Hour):
    // do what you want after the sleep of 1h here or after the switch
    fmt.Println("task finished ", rand.Intn(1000))
case <-ctx.Done():
    return
}
```